# Why $D^{\mu} D^{\nu} F_{\mu \nu}=0$ ? (Noether Identity)

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory

I have to show that:

$$D^{\mu} D^{\nu} F^A_{\mu \nu}=0$$

vanish identically. This is the generalization to non Abelian groups of $\partial^{\mu} \partial^{\nu} F_{\mu \nu}=0$, apparently called "Noether Identity".
To be explicit, for $SU(N)$:

$$F_{\mu \nu}=F^A_{\mu \nu} \tau^A   \; \; \; A=1, \dots,N$$

$$F^A_{\mu \nu}=\partial_\mu A_\nu^A -\partial_\nu A^A_{\mu} +gf^A_{\;\;BC}A^B_{\mu}A^C_{\nu}$$

$$D_\mu F^A_{\nu \rho}=\partial_\mu F^A_{\nu \rho}+g f^A_{\;\;BC}A^B_{\mu} F^C_{\nu \rho} $$

(Exercise 4.22, p.90 of Supergravity, Freedman-Van Proeyen)

Comment: Applying two times the covariant derivative, without using the explicit form of F,  you get 5 terms (one g-free, three order g^1 and one g^2). Using symmetry-antisymm. in $\mu \nu$ I can eliminate some terms, but a term of order g^1 proportional to ($\partial A$) seems to remain.

Comment: Write $D^\mu D^\nu$ as the sum of its antisymmetric part and its symmetric part. The latter can be discarded immediately. For the antisymmetric part, use that $D_{[\mu}D_{\nu]} X = F_{\mu\nu} \cdot X$ where $X$ is a gauge-covariant object and the dot means that $F_{\mu\nu}$ acts on $X$ according to the representation $X$ transforms in (cf. the definition of the Riemann tensor).